# is possible put accountkit in iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, account-kit

I have one requirement, the campaign page will embed the signup page of landing.
like this

```
campaign page
______________________
| iframe signup page |
|   ________         |
|   |      |         |
|   |      |         |
|   ________         |
______________________
```

`Accountkit` in the signup page, but we got error when open accountkit

```
Refused to display 'https://www.accountkit.com/v1.1/dialog/sms_login/' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors https://mywebsite.com".
```

is this requirement possible, or do you have other suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the header in your web server response:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' https://www.accountkit.com
```

or meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' https://www.accountkit.com">
```

[More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP)

Comment: thanks for your answer, we did not use this solution